# multidimensional array from multiple .get() requests

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, get

I am trying to write a nested array starting from a series of jquery .get() calls, based on a json like array (myHotels).

```
    function retrieveRates () {

    var myHotels =[{"srvId":"995805","hotelCountry":"GREECE","hotelCity":"45220","hotelName":"HOTEL EUROPA","starLevel":"Standard ***"},{"srvId":"106442","hotelCountry":"GREECE","hotelCity":"10514","hotelName":"ATHENS","starLevel":"Superior ****"},{"srvId":"925765","hotelCountry":"GREECE","hotelCity":"10794","hotelName":"WINSTON","starLevel":"Luxury *****"},{"srvId":"922185","hotelCountry":"GREECE","hotelCity":"10514","hotelName":"HOTEL LIBERATIN","starLevel":"Superior ****"},{"srvId":"15134","hotelCountry":"GREECE","hotelCity":"10514","hotelName":"HOTEL GRILLON","starLevel":"Luxury *****"},{"srvId":"275785","hotelCountry":"GREECE","hotelCity":"10794","hotelName":"MERIDIEN","starLevel":"Luxury *****"},{"srvId":"89302","hotelCountry":"GREECE","hotelCity":"10384","hotelName":"SAVOY","starLevel":"Luxury *****"},{"srvId":"229986","hotelCountry":"GREECE","hotelCity":"10384","hotelName":"PANAKOS","starLevel":"Superior ****"},{"srvId":"735385","hotelCountry":"GREECE","hotelCity":"10674","hotelName":"RUBEIRA","starLevel":"Luxury *****"}];

    resultsArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < myHotels.length; i++) {

      var obj = myHotels[i];
      console.log(obj.srvId)
      var propertyArray = [];
      propertyArray.push(obj.srvId);

        $.get('http://myUrl/getRoomTypes/'+obj.srvId+'?&CityId='+obj.hotelCity+'&HotelId='+obj.srvId+'&fromDateFormatted=2016-03-16&toDateFormatted=2016-03-18&numberOfNights=2&adults%5B0%5D=2&children%5B0%5D=0&boardBasis%5B0%5D=-1&residence%5B0%5D=6&nationality%5B0%5D=6&propertyType=&starRating=&perPage=10&currency=413&availability=-1&customerId=87974&allowedSingleWithChildren=1&itineraryCode=&bookedItnNumber=&customerCountry=6&passengerNationalityOrCountry=3', function(data){

          $(data).find('.booking-selection-row').each(function () {

              var roomArray = [];
              var roomDat = $(this).find('label').text();
              var roomName = roomDat.split(/\[(.*?)\]/)[0];

              var findProvider = function () {
                  providerName = "";    
                     if (! roomDat.split(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1] ) {
                     return providerName = "Avenues";
                      }
                     else {
                     return providerName = roomDat.split(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];
                     }
                     }

              var deadLine = $.trim($(this).find('span.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok-circle').text());
              roomArray.push(roomName, findProvider(), deadLine);

              $(this).find('.pricePerDay table tbody tr').each(function () {
                var dateRateArray = [];
                var thisDate = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
                var thisRate = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
                var thisBoard = $(this).find('td').eq(4).first('div').text();
                var thisAvail = $(this).find('td').eq(5).first('label').text();
                dateRateArray.push(thisDate , thisRate , thisBoard , thisAvail);
                roomArray.push(dateRateArray);
              });

            propertyArray.push(roomArray);

          });

          resultsArray.push(propertyArray);
        }, "html");

    };

};

retrieveRates();
```

The output is what I want, with the exception that in resultArray, at position [0] for each object I would like to see every time the relevant obj.srvId. Now the array writes always the srvId of the last object ("735385","hotelCountry":"GREECE"), in this fashion:

```
[["735385", ["STANDARD ROOM", "Avenues", "Deadline:  Sun, 13 Mar 2016 16:59:59", 2 more...], ["STANDARD ROOM ", "BRITHotels", "Deadline:  Sun, 13 Mar 2016 03:00:00", 2 more...], 194 more...], ["735385", ["STANDARD ROOM", "Avenues", "Deadline:  Sun, 13 Mar 2016 16:59:59", 2 more...], ["STANDARD ROOM ", "BRITHotels", "Deadline:  Sun, 13 Mar 2016 03:00:00", 2 more...], 194 more...], ["735385", ["STANDARD ROOM", "Avenues", "Deadline:  Sun, 13 Mar 2016 16:59:59", 2 more...], ["STANDARD ROOM ", "BRITHotels", "Deadline:  Sun, 13 Mar 2016 03:00:00", 2 more...], 194 more...], ["735385", ["STANDARD ROOM", "Avenues", "Deadline:  Sun, 13 Mar 2016 16:59:59", 2 more...],
```

while it should have a different obj.srvId each time.

How can I correctly push the obj.srvId into the array? It is as if the variable cannot be passed into the get() success function.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Fix your indenting, please.  That will make it far easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: thanks cale,  please let me know if it is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to be careful when putting asynchronous functions like $.get into a loop.

What's most probably happening here is that your program is looping through your MyHotels array before any of your $.get calls are done. What you need to do is iterate through your MyHotels array using the success callback function in $.get and not a for loop.

Comment: Thanks @Ting, the fact is that I also use elements from myHotels to build the url for the .get() call. How can I pass that parameter in the callback?

Comment: Thanks @Ting, starting from the comment I wrapped everything into an .each() function instead than a for loop, works fine now.